# Visual Studio Custom Template Wont Save Folders Or Files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I have a file saved as a visual studio project the uses an opengl library. I plan to use that opengl library a lot in the future so I decided to save that project as a template. Unfortunately the template did not save any of the folders or the files within those folders (These files are necessary for the library to work). Does any body have any idea why and / or a possible fix? Thanks?

Comment: Are the missing files of the template only those of the OpenGL library or do you miss any files? Are you already familiar with the VS template world?

Comment: Yeah sry i figured this problem out